# Whats wrong with this geo_shape elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do a geo_shape query for document with a location (See example document below) and I am getting NullPointerException when trying to execute it with ElasticSearch via the Chrome Addon "Sense". The exact results are at the bottom of this question...

Any help on getting the right geo_shape query to work would really be appreciated.

**Query throwing exception**

```
{
   "query": {         
     "geo_shape": {
        "location": {
           "shape": {
              "type": "polygon", 
              "coordinates": [[-87.6363976, 41.8772528], [-87.6363976, 41.8902152],[-87.62131840000001, 41.8902152], [-87.62131840000001, 41.8772528], [-87.6363976, 41.8772528]]
           }
        }

      }

    }
 }
```

***Example Document***

```
{
    "id": 1483,
    "name": "Independance Day Movie day",
    "location": [
              41.9527,
              -87.725
           ]
}
```

***Exact Results from Sense***

```
{
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[qFv-xNqxSI2oATfvmnVo8w][dev][0]: SearchParseException[[dev][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n   \"query\": { \n       \"geo_shape\": {\n          \"location\": {\n             \"shape\": {\n                \"type\": \"polygon\", \n                \"coordinates\": [[-87.6363976, 41.8772528], [-87.6363976, 41.8902152],[-87.62131840000001, 41.8902152], [-87.62131840000001, 41.8772528], [-87.6363976, 41.8772528]]\n             }\n          }\n          \n       \n       }\n        \n   \n   }\n}\n]]]; nested: NullPointerException; }]",
"status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two things wrong here. First, your `location` field should be an object that has a `type` and `coordinates` field, which I expect should be:

```
"location": {
  "type" : "point",
  "coordinates" : [ 41.9527, -87.725 ]
}
```

Note that using the array format, you are specifying them as (X, Y) or (longitude, latitude).

Secondly, your query is very close to being correct, but it requires an extra level of an array for the [polygon](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-shape-type.html#_ulink_url_http_www_geojson_org_geojson_spec_html_id4_polygon_ulink):

```
{
  "query": {         
    "geo_shape": {
      "location": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "polygon", 
          "coordinates": [
              [[-87.6363976, 41.8772528], [-87.6363976, 41.8902152],
               [-87.62131840000001, 41.8902152], [-87.62131840000001, 41.8772528],
               [-87.6363976, 41.8772528]]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The purpose of the extra layer of nesting is that it allows inner polygons to be specified for things like holes. Also, your values in your polygon will *not* contain the point that you are searching for, and the (X, Y) values are reversed for one of them regardless.

Just in case you have not already done so, then you are also required to set the GeoShape mapping in order for this to work (where `TYPE_NAME` would be the specific `index`'s `type`, such as `curl -XGET localhost:9200/index/type`):

```
{
  "mappings" : {
    "TYPE_NAME" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : { "type" : "long" },
        "name" : { "type" : "string" },
        "location" : { "type" : "geo_shape" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```